# Prove that $\Bbb{Z}[i]/J$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $J$ is a prime ideal, then prove that $\Bbb{Z}[i]/J$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$.

My attempt: Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID, then $J$ is a maximal ideal, then  $\mathbb{Z}[i]/J$ is a field. Hence the result follows. I just want some alternative approaches.

Comment: Note that the zero ideal is also prime, but not maximal.

Comment: Please, try to avoid to use mathjax on the title as much as possible because "too much mathjax" makes difficult to search similar questions through the search engines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ideal $J=0$ clearly does not work, so we can assume that there exists an element $a+bi\neq0$ in $J$. But then the integer $m=(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2>0$ is an element of $J$. Therefore the additive order of $1$ in the quotient $\Bbb{Z}[i]/J$ is a factor of $m$. Most notably it is finite. Therefore the quotient ring is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$.

---

Looks like I didn't need the assumption that $J$ is a prime ideal :-)

Comment: The idea is very similar to the one used by Servaes (+1). May be I get away with a bit less theory (no mention of PID-property)? Ho-hum.

Comment: I reall like your proof (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\Bbb{Z}[i]/J$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ for some ideal $J\subset\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Since $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID there are $a,b\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that $J=(a+bi)$. Then  $(a+bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2\in J\cap\Bbb{Z}$, from which it follows that $a^2+b^2=0$. But then $a+bi=0$ so $\Bbb{Z}[i]/J$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$, a contradiction.

Comment: By construction $a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$ is an element of $J$. And because $a$ and $b$ are integers, so is $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: Because the quotient $\Bbb{Z}[i]/J$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$, the additive order of $1$ in the quotient is infinite. This means no positive integer is contained in $J$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the unique ring homomorphism $\chi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}[i]/J$, $n\mapsto n+J$.

If $J\ne\{0\}$, $\chi$ is not an isomorphism: it is not injective, as $x\in J$, $x\ne0$, implies $x\bar{x}\in\ker\chi$.

If $J=\{0\}$, $\chi$ is not an isomorphism: it is not surjective, as $i\notin\chi(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: The OP said "not isomorphic" not "not isomorphic via the canonical homomorphism $\chi$". (I suppose the ring homomorphisms shouldn't be unitary by default.)

Comment: @user26857 There is *exactly* one homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R$, where $R$ is any ring (with identity). So if the isomorphism exists, it must be this one. I assumed unitary homomorphisms, of course. Anyway, if a ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, it is a domain, so a ring homomorphism must preserve $1$.